# Cannot fetch user information in PHP

Tags: php

I'm making a profile picture uploader but there is a problem, the variable `$user['username']` is not detected by my code/system.

**Query:**

```
$updateprofilepicture = "UPDATE users SET profilepicture = '{$target_file}' WHERE username='{$user['username']}'";
mysqli_query($mysqli, $updateprofilepicture);
echo $updateprofilepicture; ## To Check the Query
```

**Expected Output:**

> UPDATE users SET profilepicture = 'pictures/profile/WIN_20160628_16_59_19_Pro.jpg' WHERE username='virtualAnon'

**The Query I recieved:**

> UPDATE users SET profilepicture = 'pictures/profile/WIN_20160628_16_59_19_Pro.jpg' WHERE username=''

**My Codes:**

```
<?php
  # Essential files, please don't erase it!
  require_once("../functions.php");
  require_once("../db-const.php");
?>
      <?php
        $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        ## connect mysql server
            $mysqli = new mysqli("---confedential---", "---confedential---", "---confedential---", "---confedential---");
            # check connection
            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
                exit();
            }
        ## query database
            # fetch data from mysql database
          $main = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='".$id."' LIMIT 1";

            if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
                $user = $result->fetch_array();
            } else {
                echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
                exit();
            }

          // update status to online
          $timestamp = time();
          $sql = "UPDATE users SET status={$timestamp} WHERE id={$_SESSION['user_id']}";
          $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

      ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<br><br>

    <?php
    $target_dir = "pictures/profile/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $conn = new mysqli("mysql9.000webhost.com", "a5532550_prspkt", "kirk05230912", "a5532550_data");
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 200000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            echo "<br>";
            $updateprofilepicture = "UPDATE users SET profilepicture = '{$target_file}' WHERE username='{$user['username']}'";
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $updateprofilepicture);
            echo "Success!";
            echo $updateprofilepicture;
            echo "<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }


    ?>

    <p> hello <?php $user['username']; ?>
```

Comment: echo the $user['username'] and confirm it  is empty ?

Comment: Tried that, and it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: where from you get that $user array ?

Comment: your id column is int or varchar ?   id ='".$id."'

Comment: I got the $user array at my database, `$user = $result->fetch_array();` and my ID Column is in Int

Comment: not need to use single quotes for int data type id =".$id."

Comment: What does `var_dump($user)` show?

Comment: initialize the $user =array(); and confirm that $user have atleast one user data value print_r($user);

Comment: You can post your answer and solution to this answer to check if it's working :)

Comment: @virtualAnon If echoing `$user['username']` echoes nothing, it means it's empty, which is why your query doesn't work.